# Lost notifications after installing XFCE

Tags: 12.04, notification

Today I noticed that I don't see any notifications. Is there a way to reset notification settings. It happend after I installed xfce on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Ubuntu's default notify-osd daemon installed? Maybe it is in conflict with XFCE's native notification daemon..

Apparently, when it comes to notification daemons, there can be only one.. unfortunately, the right one does not get run, and the packages aren't marked to conflict. XFCE developers closed the bug report, so I assume that according to XFCE developers, you are not supposed to have Gnome and XFCE installed on the same system.

Why not just remove one? XFCE's notification daemon isn't tied to XFCE AFAIK (though I haven't actually used it under any DE other than XFCE), although it does rely on xfconf. Both NotifyOSD and xfce4-notifyosd are both implementations of the FreeDesktop Notification Standard so notifications would work equally well under any of them (although I prefer xfce4-notifyosd as it provides an 'X' button on notifications without patching and it has support for buttons on notifications).

Since NotifyOSD is totally unconfigurable (and it's meant to be "just there" hence why you can't close its notifications manually and why it doesn't support buttons on notifications), XFCE can't change its settings. To do what you want, you can either get rid of NotifyOSD and use XFCE's notification daemon (which will start once NotifyOSD goes) or get rid of xfce4-notifyosd and use leolik's patched NotifyOSD which does let you set the position of its notifications.

If you're running Precise (which is what I suspect as xfce4-notifyosd in Natty would actually conflict because they share a file), however, leolik's PPA does not have a Precise build.

Long-story-short...remove one of the notify applications.

[source](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6994)

Comment: what are the actual names for those packages. I've tried sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyosd but it tells me there is no package xfce4-notifyosd. And I would like to remove NotifyOSD because I also prefer xfce notify daemon.

Comment: As I recall it would be xfce4-notifyd. So to remove it would be `sudo apt-get remove xfce4-notifyd`